# Delphi Object Pascal corresponding run-time calls of TBindNavigator

Tags: delphi, livebindings

My question is about Delphi Object Pascal corresponding run-time calls of TBindNavigator component buttons.
I'm interesting of the following buttons:

- "Post";
- "Cancel";
- "Refresh".

How can I implement it in the code without TBindNavigator?
Would you please clarify this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot make much sense of your question. Do you mean how to get notified when the user clicks a certain button on that navigator ? If so, then write a handler for the [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Fmx.Bind.Navigator.TCustomBindNavigator.OnClick) event.

Comment: well,that's unclear what you are exactly asking..

Comment: Is this correct? You want to do three things that TBindNavigator is useful for, but you want to do them without using TBindNavigator?  If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I want to do three thing without TBindNavigator. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to implement the necessary actions with simultaneous check if they are enabled etc. then you do not need `TBindNavigator` at all. The easiest way is the following:

The sample for an FMX Form:

1. Add a `TActionList` to your form.
2. Add a `New Standard Action` form `LiveBindings` node of necessary `TFMXBindNavigatePost`, `TFMXBindNavigateCancel` etc. class.
3. Select this action and set `Datasource` property.
4. Assign the action to the necessary `TButton` or other control.

Steps 2-4 can be done in the other way as well.

2. Selet the control (i.e. `TButton`), select property `Action` and click the arrow on the right.
3. Select `New standard action` then `LiveBindings`. Select the necessary class `TFMXBindNavigate*`. The action will be assigned to the `TButton`.
4. Select `TActionList` and choose the added action and set `DataSource` property.

The action will be kept up-to-date by `LiveBindings`. The necessary controls will become `Enabled`-`Disabled` and will act as buttons of `TBindNavigator`.

Comment: The Datasource in each case, should be a BindSourceDB.